# Selenium webdriver Java code to access headers and sub headers in HTML

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to access headers and subheaders of HTML using Java selenium webdriver . Could you please say what will be the java code to access the headers and sub headers of HTML.

```
<div class="containerShadowBottom"><div class="containerShadowRight">
<div class="containerShadowBL">
<div class="containerShadowUR">
<div class="containerShadowBR">
<div class="portletContent">
<h1 class="" id="Admin" style="cursor:pointer;" ondblclick="toggleClassName('AdminDiv','hide','detail',true);toggleClassName('AdminToggle','toggleUp','toggleDown');">
<a href="#" id="AdminToggle" class=" toggleDown" onclick="toggleClassName('AdminDiv','hide','detail',true);toggleClassName('AdminToggle','toggleUp','toggleDown');"></a>Admin</h1><div id="AdminDiv" class="hide">
```

Comment: Have you tried something like [`driver.findElement(By.tagName("head"))`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html)? Where is actually your problem?

Comment: @LaurentG This the code used in HTML <h1 class="" id="Admin" style="cursor:pointer;" ondblclick="toggleClassName('AdminDiv','hide','detail',true);toggleClassName('AdminToggle','toggleUp','toggleDown');"><a href="#" id="AdminToggle" class="toggleUp" onclick="toggleClassName('AdminDiv','hide','detail',true);toggleClassName('AdminToggle','toggleUp','toggleDown');"></a>Admin</h1> and in java i am using the code as driver.findElement(By.id("Admin")).click();

Comment: Gokul, did they worked for you? here, header is not an issue in finding elements; make sure there are duplicate elements with id Admin.

Comment: @PrashanthSams The above code did not worked for me. I have got the above HTML code using firebug and I am trying to click the header using the above JAVA code but it did not works :(

Comment: I feel thee are number of h1 header tags in your HTML. Can I have your site? or more detailed parents of this tag

Comment: @PrashanthSams I have pasted the code in my question and there are ten H1 header tags available in my HTML code but all the 10 headers have different ids. Using a unique H1 header id only i am calling driver.findElement(By.id("Admin")).click();

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='AdminToggle']")).click(); try this or driver.findElement(By.id("AdminToggle")).click();

Comment: okay; let me post the same in Answer :)

Comment: @PrashanthSams I have tried using below code: driver.findElement(By.id("AdminToggle")).click(); I have sent contact request to you in Skype could you please add me in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='AdminToggle']")).click();
```

or |

```
driver.findElement(By.id("AdminToggle")).click();
```